# Why does this code always get a SynchronizationLockException?

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, locking

What's wrong with this code ?

I always get a

> Object synchronization method was
>   called from an unsynchronized block of
>   code

Exception on

```
System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(m_sqlConnection)
```

But... It doesn't matter whether I put the Monitor statement inside or outside the try-catch-finally-block, in any combination, I always get this exception.

That is, after I compiled the code.
If I let it run again after getting the first exception, it works fine...
It's always after recompilation...

```
Public Shared Function GetDataTable(ByRef strSQL As String, ByRef dt As System.Data.DataTable, Optional ByRef strTableName As String = "ThisTable") As Integer
            Dim daQueryTable As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter = Nothing



            Try
                System.Threading.Monitor.TryEnter(m_sqlConnection, 5000)

                If isDataBaseConnectionOpen() = False Then OpenSQLConnection()


                daQueryTable = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, m_sqlConnection)
                dt = New System.Data.DataTable(strTableName)

                daQueryTable.Fill(dt)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Log(ex)
                Return -1
            Finally
                m_sqlConnection.Close()
                System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(m_sqlConnection)
                daQueryTable.Dispose()
                daQueryTable = Nothing
            End Try

            Return dt.Rows.Count
        End Function ' GetDataTable
```

C# version:

```
public static int GetDataTable(ref string strSQL, ref System.Data.DataTable dt, ref string strTableName = "ThisTable")
{
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter daQueryTable = null;



    try {
        System.Threading.Monitor.TryEnter(m_sqlConnection, 5000);

        if (isDataBaseConnectionOpen() == false)
            OpenSQLConnection();


        daQueryTable = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, m_sqlConnection);
        dt = new System.Data.DataTable(strTableName);

        daQueryTable.Fill(dt);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log(ex);
        return -1;
    } finally {
        m_sqlConnection.Close();
        System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(m_sqlConnection);
        daQueryTable.Dispose();
        daQueryTable = null;
    }

    return dt.Rows.Count;
} // GetDataTable
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're calling [`TryEnter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42h9d380.aspx), but ignoring the result - so you're going to try to exit the monitor even if you don't own it. You should take appropriate action if `TryEnter` returns false, such as exiting the method.

Comment: Hmm, in other words, TryEnter doesn't throw after timeout. Damn... But found the error: I lock on OpenSQLConnection, but never unlock.

Comment: @Quandary: No, it returns a value. Always check the documentation :) Either way your code is broken though - you'd still hit the finally block and try to close the connection, then exit the lock. (Actually, closing the connection if you haven't acquired the lock would be awful - you could be closing a connection that someone else is using...)

Answer (score -1):

Since the [`lock` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is a shortcut for `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit`, I would recommend that you simple use the `lock` statement and ignore the `Monitor` classes.

Comment: And since the lock statement has no timout (in case I'm wrong, it's a very very high one), such as TryEnter, I would recommend that you use TryEnter instead of lock.